# Не видит файл на устройстве

Tags: java, android

хочу сделать так чтобы считывались строки из файла. Я перепробовал все. 
Вот фрагмент кода

```
File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/documents/Hhhhh.txt");
try {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String line;

  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      array[size] = line;
      size++;
  }
  text_film.setText(array[2]);
}
catch (IOException e) {
  text_film.setText("gehufn");
}
```

В чем тут не так?

Comment: вы в манифесте разрешение дали на работу с файлами?

Comment: Да. Но сейчас нашёл ошибку там.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.premission.READ_EXTREMAL_STORAGE" />

но всеравно не читает файл

Comment: попробуйте директорию писать так `File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
File file = new File(dir, "example.txt");`

Comment: Всеравно не видит

Comment: то есть исключение вылетает?

Comment: Да.  То что я написал в исключении